# Positioning legend title on top of horizontal legend causes loss of interactivity in ggiraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggiraph

When I used guides() specifications to customise legend appearance, I found that the interactive nature of the legend in the plot is lost.

The following code modified from the example in the ggiraph documentation.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

dat <- data.frame(
  name = c( "Guy", "Ginette", "David", "Cedric", "Frederic" ),
  gender = c( "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male" ),
  height = c(169, 160, 171, 172, 171 ) )
p <- ggplot(dat, aes( x = name, y = height, fill = gender,
                      data_id = name ) ) +
  geom_bar_interactive(stat = "identity")

p1 <- p +  scale_fill_manual_interactive(
  values = c(Male = "#0072B2", Female = "#009E73"),
  data_id = function(breaks) { as.character(breaks)},
  tooltip = function(breaks) { as.character(breaks)},
  onclick = function(breaks) { paste0("alert(\"", as.character(breaks), "\")") },
  labels = function(breaks) {
    lapply(breaks, function(br) {
      label_interactive(
        as.character(br),
        data_id = as.character(br),
        onclick = paste0("alert(\"", as.character(br), "\")"),
        tooltip = as.character(br)
      )
    })
  }
) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title.position = "top")) +
  theme(legend.position="top")  

girafe_options(girafe(ggobj = p1),
               opts_hover_key(girafe_css("stroke:red", text="stroke:none;fill:red")))
```

Without the `guides(fill=guide_legend(title.position = "top"))` line, the legend retains its interactivity.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the title position via `guides()` you could achieve your desired result without losing the interactivity via the `guide` argument of `scale_fill_manual_interactive`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

dat <- data.frame(
  name = c("Guy", "Ginette", "David", "Cedric", "Frederic"),
  gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male"),
  height = c(169, 160, 171, 172, 171)
)
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(
  x = name, y = height, fill = gender,
  data_id = name
)) +
  geom_bar_interactive(stat = "identity")

p1 <- p + scale_fill_manual_interactive(
  values = c(Male = "#0072B2", Female = "#009E73"),
  data_id = function(breaks) {
    as.character(breaks)
  },
  tooltip = function(breaks) {
    as.character(breaks)
  },
  onclick = function(breaks) {
    paste0("alert(\"", as.character(breaks), "\")")
  },
  labels = function(breaks) {
    lapply(breaks, function(br) {
      label_interactive(
        as.character(br),
        data_id = as.character(br),
        onclick = paste0("alert(\"", as.character(br), "\")"),
        tooltip = as.character(br)
      )
    })
  },
  guide = guide_legend(title.position = "top")
) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")

girafe_options(
  girafe(ggobj = p1),
  opts_hover_key(girafe_css("stroke:red", text = "stroke:none;fill:red"))
)
```

[image]